# How to use React-recoil in IE11?

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, next.js, recoiljs

Is there a way to use `react-recoil` in IE11 ?

I know IE has been dead now, but somehow I need to support older browsers like `IE11`

I was just created a normal application using with `create-next-app`.

```
# in package.json
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "recoil": "^0.7.5",
  ...
}
```

When I try to use `react-recoil`, it keeps throwing endless errors like

`This element does not support 'attachShadow'`

```
The above error occurred in the <Portal> component:

 at Portal ...
 at ReactDevOverlay ...
 at construct ...
 at AppContainer ...
 at Root ...

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, Container.
```

Does anyone know how to use `react-recoil` in IE11 ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official doc](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/installation#es5-support), you need to compile your code with **Babel** and use preset `@babel/preset-env`. However, it is not recommended since ES6 is needed.

Comment: thanks :) I'll check official doc